# What does "off you go" mean?

Tags: idioms

I came across the phrase **off you go** which has been frequently used in many movies.

Especially, the movie *John Carter* impressed me with this phrase.
What does it mean in different scenarios/cases?

Comment: Please give an example of the context in which it is being used as part of your question. Normally, “Off you go” is a way of sending someone, especially a child, away to do something particular—but it may have other meanings in specific contexts.

Comment: In the movie "John Carter". The scenario is bunch of maidservants standing around the protagonist. Suddently, a supervisor came into the room and seems got something important need to talk with the protagonist,then he gave a waring glance to the leader of these maids. the leader who is a old lady then turn to these maids says:" off you go." then all of them walked out this room including this old lady. (I apologise for my poor english if any misunderstanding leads to you.)

Comment: In that case, it is simply a less abrasive way of saying, “Shoo” or, “Go away”. Note how it is the head maid who says it to her ‘subordinates’—it may be less abrasive than, “Go away”, but it is still an order. ‘Off’ here means ‘away’; you might also hear, “Off with you”, which is more blunt.

Comment: So appreciate for your elaborate explanation. if there has a way for using it in a positive way? if so, would you mind to give a simple instance ? cheers!

Comment: I’m not sure what you mean by a ‘positive way’, exactly, but it is for example a very natural phrase for a parent to use when telling their child to go brush their teeth and get ready for bed at night: “All right, that’s enough television for night, love. Go on up and brush your teeth now, and get into your pyjamas and get ready for bed. Go on, off you go.”

Comment: I rewatched the movie "John Carter" just now and found this scenario i mentioned previously. the tone of voice and expression from the head maid  are exactly like what you explained above! Thank you so much! LOVE YOU!

Comment: It may not be quite rude but it is dismissive.  You probably wouldn't say that to your boss and might only use it playfully with a peer or significant other.

Comment: @Kristina Lopez, what does significant other means? people who are important to me like my parents? and i would not say this to my boss but punch his face. lol. thank you for nice suggestion.

Comment: @ConquerorW, "significant other" means boyfriend, girlfriend or spouse.  In other words, regardless of what we secretly *think* of our bosses, parents, etc., we probably wouldn't *say* "off you go" to them out of respect, but we might say it in jest to our friends or someone else close to us who would know we were saying that to be funny, not disrespectful. :-)

Comment: I'm not sure why this is on ELU and not ELL.

Comment: Another "positive use" would be using it as "Go on, get going,..." for example to a child thats asks to be a allowed to go to the corner shop to buy an ice cream. Then, as a parent, after allowing it you could add to the (still waiting) child. "Off you go." as a way of additional affirmation that it really may go now.

Comment: @Kristina Lopez, it does make sense to me now! Cheers! what an amazing website with great users! thanks again!

Comment: @skymninge, thank you! this is my first time to post question, and all these oustanding anwsers are surprised to me. i feel so touchable and heart warming from your helps. So appreciate!

Answer (score 9):

The meaning of “off you go” is somewhat difficult for an English language learner for two reasons. First, *off* has many meanings; second, the word order is unusual.

*Off* in the context of this phrase means *away*, with a sense of definite separation. You will also hear this sense of *off* in phrases about leaving or creating distance, such as “walked off”, “drove off”, “chased off”, and “off with his head”.

The more conventional word order for the command would be “you go off” (or “go off”), meaning “go away”, but the word order “off you go” is more idiomatic.

**See:**
[New English Dictionary, volume O](http://archive.org/stream/oed07arch#page/72/mode/2up)

Answer (score 8):

In common usage, the phrase *off you go* has a patronising or dismissive connotation.

It is something you say to dismiss a child - *Off you go to school now* or *Off you go and tidy your room*.

It is not used in addressing a superior, a customer or in similar situations where you would not wish to be thought of as even slightly rude.

Answer (score 2):

'Off you go' means you can leave now. Usage : If you want someone to go away or go home, especially a kid but not in a rude way like 'get lost'.

Answer (score 2):

I have seen *off you go* being used in two ways:

1. As a casual dismissal message.

> 'OK, we're all done. Off you go.'

2. As a way of saying one can start something (like a speech or a presentation).

> 'Are you ready to start?'
>
> 'Yes.'
>
> 'Okay, off you go!'

Answer (score 1):

I have run into the use of this expression with a different meaning, not having the sense of giving an order but to indicate that someone is ready to take action

Just make sure your parachute is properly setup and off you go! - In this case it means you are all set

Answer (score 1):

I heard this idiom being used by one of the judges in *Britain's Got Talent*. It signalled the candidate to start his performance.

Answer (score 1):

I think it is important to note that it is dismissive, you wouldn't say it to someone like a customer or boss, you might say it to a child or you might say it in jest to a friend.  Also it is not really used in the US, it is an English expression.

Comment: Chenmunka expressed most of this.

Comment: It is also not true that it is not used in the US. It is perfectly common in American English, too, though perhaps not quite as common as in British English.

Answer (score -1):

For me, it is like " you go girl! " - or  "Get down to work!" :)