# Why is "Off you go" correct?

Tags: grammar

Can anyone explain why is it grammatically correct to say "off you go"? Well, it seems really strange to me.

Comment: It's a different way of saying “You go off.” You could also say “Up you climb” for “You climb up” or “Here I am” for “I am here.” I'm sure there's a name for putting the preposition in the front like that. Hopefully another user knows it.

Comment: @P1h3r1e3d13 Your answer looks so true. Let's see if someone else say the same thing.

Comment: Related: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/122331/what-does-off-you-go-mean

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some adverbs, including directional ones, can be put first in the clause, for emphasis or rhythm:

> Down they fell, all the way to the bottom.
>
> Away he sped, pedals whizzing round.
>
> Off he ran.

With a first or second person subject it is usually an exclamation, but grammatically it is the same as with any other subject. Verbs other than "go" don't seem to fit very well in this case:

> In I go!
>
> Off you go!
>
> Away we go!